# http://localhost:3000/ keeps loading forever

Tags: reactjs, localhost

I did a `npx create-react-app Xname` and everything was going okay. Today as I was editing my code, the page refreshed and kept on refreshing. So it never loads basically. I have no error on the Terminal. I tried many things like opening another project, using a different port (3001), killing all ports, using another Browser, Restarting my Laptop, etc but the problem remains. No project can be opened to the browser. The browser keeps on loading forever. Does anybody know what I can do in this case?

Comment: What was the last change you made before it broke?

Comment: Something on my code, converted basically a class component to functional component using hooks..

Comment: And if you undo that change is it fixed? You need to narrow this down to a [mre] or we can't help you.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. I got it ! I forgot to add a dot at the Context.Provider... :)

Answer (score 0):

i restarted my pc and it worked for me. I think the app was running on port 3000 already in the background.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32519404)